# how do write: It is what it is. ? Without the indefinite it

Tags: grammaticality

How do you write

> It is what it is.

without the indefinite it?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  You need to give us a bit more to work with.  For example, you could say *That's that*.  Or you could say, *That's the way the cookie crumbles.*.  Or even just *Oh well.*

Comment: You can't. "It is what it is" is a fixed idiom of acceptance.

Comment: You could write, “What is, is.”

Comment: Don't use a pronoun at all—use the actual noun: *The wine is what the wine is.* Unless of course you don't have a definite noun in mind; in which case, you are forced to use the indefinite (or dummy) pronoun.